# Global Ignore Spelling Directive in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, directive

In Visual Studio 2022, you can add the directive `// Ignore Spelling: WordToIgnore` in a file to ignore said word. Is there a way to do this globally for the solution? I do not want to add it to the Ignore Words File because I do not want to affect other solutions. I also would like to not add this line of code to every file that I want it in.

Comment: Not a complete answer but might help: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EWoodruff.VisualStudioSpellCheckerVS2022andLater&ssr=false#qna in the Q&A section look for Leonard Harris's question and author response: "Assuming this is related to the code analyzer, it's a current limitation of the code analyzer"

Comment: [You can also choose to ignore spelling issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/text-spell-checker?view=vs-2022). By choosing to ignore the issue, Visual Studio will create an exclusion.dic file in the AppData directory on the local computer. When you choose to ignore a word, the spell checker ignores that word in all instances of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

A claim made within this question is in direct conflict with fact:

There is no such thing as a `// Ignore Spelling:` "directive" in Visual Studio 2022.

I have never seen such a "directive" being mentioned in any documentation I have read, (and I have read a lot,) and an attempt to try to include such a directive within my code to see if by any miracle it works was just a waste of time: of course, it does not work.

Maybe some plugin used by the author supports such a "directive".

(Perhaps "Visual Studio Spell Checker" by EWSoftware.)

Which means that the answer that the author is seeking must lie within the documentation of that plugin.

Visual Studio 2022 comes with its own built-in spell checker, which is configurable via .editorconfig, and which can be configured to learn ("exclude" in microsoft parlance) words at the solution scope or even at the project scope.  However, I cannot recommend using the Visual Studio 2022 built-in spell checker, because it [does not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77237535/773113).)